# N'y-a-t-il pas de mot « proprement français » pour désigner le suspense ?

Tags: demande-de-mot

Selon [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspense), le nom masculin « suspense », qui signifie une attente anxieuse, est un anglicisme, venant du mot anglais à orthographe identique, lui-même venant du mot français « suspens » (l'adjectif, sans doute).

[Le Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/suspense/75958) va dans le même sens :

> (anglais *suspense*, du français [suspens 1](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/suspens/75955))

[Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/suspense) indique également qu'il s'agit d'un anglicisme.

Quant au nom masculin « suspens », celui-ci n'est, selon [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspens#Nom_commun) et [Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/suspens), qu'une francisation de l'anglicisme « suspense ».

À tout cela s'ajoute le fait qu'aucun des deux noms masculins ne figure dans le [Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr).

N'y-a-t-il donc pas de mot qui ne soit pas un anglicisme pour désigner une attente anxieuse dans un œuvre cinématographique ou littéraire ou dans la vie réelle ?

Comment: Pour moi, il y a une grosse différence entre anglicisme et un mot qui à l'origine était français ou qui est d'origine latine. Un film à suspense me semble bien français mais **un thriller** me semble un anglicisme proprement dit. La langue française dit "thriller" avec difficulté (cad, du point de vue prononciation) et ça sort: triller.

Comment: "Appréhension" me semble approprié. Le fait qu'il soit composé de 4 syllabes fait qu'il a été vite remplacé par le plus court "suspense" prononcé en 2 syllabes.

Comment: @Necklondon appréhension, dans la vie réelle, mais pas pour un genre de film. D'ailleurs, c'est le même mot en anglais. Du latin en directe...je fais des commentaires, pas des phrases complètes]

Comment: On peut dire “tension” .

Comment: @Lambie Pire, l'usage hésite entre deux prononciations. Personnellement, j'entends plus souvent "srilleur"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat D'accord, mais c'est vraiment un anglicisme alors que "suspense" ne l'est pas.

Comment: @Lambie Je préfère me déférer aux dictionnaires plutôt que d'estimer que « suspense » n'est pas un anglicisme tout simplement parce qu'un autre mot, « thriller », a l'air plus anglais. D'ailleurs, nul des deux syllabes de « thriller » n'est prononcée comme en anglais alors que dans le cas de « suspense », la deuxième syllabe est prononcée, à dessein, exactement comme en anglais, y compris en faisant entendre le _n_, chose qui ne se fait jamais en français.

Comment: "thriller" n'a pas **l'air plus anglais**, c'est de l'anglais. Et puis, suspense vient du latin. Je ne vois pas pourquoi vous sentez le besoin de me critiquer pour avoir mentionné ces faits. Les français ne prononcent pas le th de thriller, voilà ce que je voulais dire. C'est évident, non? Je ne comparerais pas la prononciation de suspense et thriller pour évoquer la francité d'un terme...

Comment: On trouve par ailleurs [_à suspense_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suspense/1), la locution adjectivale, au TLFi.

Comment: @Lambie Ce que je veux dire est tout simplement que le caractère ou l'origine de « thriller » n'affecte en rien l'origine du nom masculin « suspense ». Vous contestez que ce dernier est, tel que l'indique les dictionnaires, une francisation d'un anglicisme. Si c'était le cas, « un suspense » et « le suspense » seraient sans aucun doute apparus dans la littérature bien avant qu'ils le sont, [au milieu du vingtième siècle](https://bit.ly/3weYhgG).

Comment: @peanutjelly "Ce que je veux dire est tout simplement que le caractère ou l'origine de « thriller » n'affecte en rien à l'origine du nom masculin « suspense »." Je n'ai jamais dit cela. **Je dis que les mots d'origine latines me sembleraient toujours plus français qu'un mot anglais utilisé en français**. Enfin, J'ai droit à mon opinion, non?

Comment: @Lambie Quand vous dites que « il y a une grosse différence entre anglicisme et un mot qui à l'origine était français ou qui est d'origine latine » et que « "suspense" ne l'est pas », vous présentez votre opinion comme un fait.

Comment: C''est un **fait**. Le mot suspense vient du latin (suspensus) en passant par l'anglais. Le mot thriller vient de l'anglais. //TLFi: Empr. à l'angl.suspense, lui-même empr., notamment dans la loc. in suspense, au fr. suspens* et att. dep. 1440 au sens de « état d'incertitude angoissante, d'appréhension », d'où son empl. en appos. pour qualifier des œuvres caractérisées par de telles situations (1952 suspense novels « romans à suspense » ds NED Suppl.2).

Comment: @Lambie **Le mot suspense vient du latin (suspensus) en passant par l'anglais.** C'est justement ce qui fait de lui un anglicisme. Nier cela reviendrait soit à contester la définition du mot « anglicisme » soit à nier le fait bien connu qu'une grande proportion des mots anglais viennent eux-mêmes du latin ou du français.

Answer (score 3):

***Suspense*** ne figure pas encore dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie française mais le suspense prendra fin d'ici peu : la neuvième édition en étant au mot <s>*Sommairement* à la date du 12 février 2022</s> *Spermatophyte* à la date du 16 mars 2023.

On peut noter que ce mot a été utilisé par Alain Decaux en 2012 dans [son discours de réception de Max Gallo](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/reponse-au-discours-de-reception-de-m-max-gallo).

> *[...] cela et bien d’autres choses font naître un **suspense** qui, d’évidence, annonce le genre et le style que nous apprécions en vous.*

On trouve aussi maintenant le mot *suspense* dans une citation présente dans l'entrée *[savamment](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9S0648)* de la neuvième édition (c'est moi qui graisse) :

> ▪ *Par extension.* Avec maîtrise, habileté. *Les fleurs de cette composition sont savamment disposées. Un **suspense** savamment ménagé*.

Il n'existe pas de mot unique pouvant remplacer efficacement *suspense* et le besoin ne s'en fait pas sentir.

Comment: How about *attente anxieuse* or *attente anguoissée*?  Certaiinly in the sentence *les auteurs utilisent les ressorts dramatiques classiques de l'attente anxieuse, de la surprise, du quiproquo pour mieux brouiller les pistes du spectateur ...* (found by *Google*), the phrae *attente anxieuse* should be translated as *suspense*.

Comment: @PeterShor *Attente anxieuse/angoissée* correctly describes the meaning indeed but using it would generally fall flat: *– J'aime bien les films à attente angoissée ! – What??*